# MongoDb's $set equivalent in its java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there a way in which I can modify the value of one of the keys in MongoDb via its Java Driver. I tried out the following:

```
someCollection.update(DBObject query, DBObject update);
someCollection.findAndModify(DBObject query, DBObject update);
```

But both the functions completely replace the queried document with the updated document. What is the way to update only one of the value of a particular key as in the case of using $set in the mongo shell.(apart from making a completely new Document with all fields copied and one of the fields updated).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("age", 10));
set.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("name", "Some Name"));
someCollection.update(someSearchQuery, set);
```

Also look at [this example](http://vsbabu.org/mt/archives/2010/03/02/simple_mongodbjava_example.html).

Comment: What is the second statement for? And it seems there is no function called append in the class com.mongodb.DBCollection. But it works fine without the second statement. Thanks

Comment: Second statement show that you can add so many 'set' as you want in single update. It was my mistake, instead of someCollection.append should be set.append, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi this is not correct answer, it will only set the last value. See the answer I posted below

Comment: Yekmer Simsek is right. Your code will only update the last one.

Comment: @astonia, is this answer correct now? I dont tell any difference between this answer and Yekmer's

Answer (score 30):

```
BasicDBObject carrier = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("YOUR_QUERY_STRING", YOUR_QUERY_VALUE);

BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", carrier);
carrier.put("a", 6);
carrier.put("b", "wx1");        
myColl.updateMany(query, set);
```

This should work, the answer which is accepted is not right above.

Comment: @Yekmer Simsek :Please help me out the issue with Mongo Update .I have requested it at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406027/mongodb-java-api-failing-to-update?noredirect=1#comment93686929_53406027

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions mentioned above worked for me. I realized that the query should be a Document type and not a BasicDBObject :

```
Document set = new Document("$set", new Document("firstName","newValue"));

yourMongoCollection.updateOne(new Document("_id",objectId), set);
```

Where "yourMongoCollection" is of type "MongoCollection" and "objectId" of type "ObjectId"

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer pointed me in the right direction, but the code to add a 2nd object to the update did not work for me. The following did:

```
BasicDBObject newValues = new BasicDBObject("age", 10);
newValues.append("name", "Some Name");
BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", newValues);
collection.update(someSearchQuery, set);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, unless I want to reconfigure/reformat/"re-type" my values I'd go only with `findAndModify` and **not** `update`.

Here is a fully working example for c&p purposes... Enjoy:

```
    Boolean updateValue(DB db, DBCollection collection, String id, String key, Object newValue)
    {
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(<collection name>);

        // Identify your required document (id, key, etc...)
        DBObject     query      = new BasicDBObject("_ID",<ID or key value>);
        DBObject     update     = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject(key, newValue));

        //These flags will guarantee that you'lls get the updated result
        DBObject     result     = collection.findAndModify(query, null, null, false, update,true, true);

        //Just for precaution....
        if(result == null)
            return false;

        return result.get(key).equals(newValue);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documents, `$set` is an alise for `$addFields`, so just use that:

```
        var iterable = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.addFields(new Field("foo", "bar"))
        ));
```