# update map directly in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, dictionary, updates

I have a collection in mongoDB and its documents have 3 fields like below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "5396ad5de4b09ea27a641ed6"} , 
    "word" : "test_word" , 
    "doc_occurrence" : "'total':25,'sport':10" ,
    "total_occurrence" : "'total':32,'sport':15"
}
```

I want to know can I update value of the key directly using java (using dot for example)? or I have to get map completely and update this way?

If i have to use sub-document to update values through dot notation,what type of data type I must use to keep sub-doument fields?

p.s: above collection structure is what is printed in java.
collection structure in mongo terminal is like this:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5396d751e4b0cabeab49be0b"), 
   "word" : "test_word", 
   "doc_occurrence" : { "total" : 25, "sport" : 10 }, 
   "total_occurrence" : { "total" : 32, "sport" : 15 }  
}
```

Comment: What mongodb driver for Java do you use?

Comment: i use mongo-java-driver-2.10.1

Comment: OK, that one seems to represent the JSON documents as [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html)s. You should use its methods to build/modify the document.

Comment: Actually the [collection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) insert method takes a [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBObject.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These you can update a single field by the following:

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
        "_id", new ObjectId("5396ad5de4b09ea27a641ed6")
    );
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject(
        "$set", new BasicDBObject("doc_occurance.total", 30)
    );

    table.update(query,update);
```

So this uses the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator and the use of "dot notation" to indentify and singularly update an element in a sub-document. You can specify as many fields as you need within the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator part of the update.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). This question more or less treats your problem: [MongoDb's $set equivalent in its java Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943434/mongodbs-set-equivalent-in-its-java-driver).

I am also not sure about the structure of your document ... maybe you forgot a few `{ }` at the `doc_occurrence` and `total_occurrence`.