# Find document and insert nested document

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to find a MongoDB Document in Java and then add a nested document to that original document but every example I see online for nested documents is inserting the full document at once.

Comment: use $set to insert a nested document, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943434/mongodbs-set-equivalent-in-its-java-driver

Comment: Thank you, Much appreciated