# MongoDb Java API failing to update

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update MongoDB records based on two Search parameters which are Long values. I am using the below code for the update.But I am not able to figure out the mistakes which is making the updates failed. Appreciate any help from the experts.

```
try {

//Code to get the connection to MongoDb
//code to get the Collection 

        long newupdateValue=-101L;

        BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("orderId", newupdateValue));          


        Configurer queryConfig = Configurer.getInstance(queriesFile);

        String[] Ids= // List of Ids 



        long OrderId= //Get the Order Id

        for (String id: Ids) {

            long idInLong = Long.parseLong(id);

            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            searchQuery.put("orderId", OrderId);
            searchQuery.put("id", idInLong );

            WriteResult wr = collection.updateMulti(searchQuery, updateQuery);
            System.out.println(wr);

        }

    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        MongoDbConnectionManager.closeMongoDbConnection(mongoClient);

    }
```

MongoDb field Details are:

{

```
"orderId" : NumberLong("99"),

"id"      : NumberLong("1234"),
```

}

Comment: What does the write result say? It will not only tell you the number of updates but also the number of matches. If the matches say `0` then the query criteria is wrong.

Comment: Yes I am getting zero.I have checked in the database for the validity of my searchquery values.They are present.

Comment: Well your Java code does not think they are valid, so something is off. Either the query parameters are not what you think they are, or you are pointing at the wrong collection. Time to do some logging and checking.

Comment: I am hitting the right collection. Is there any mistake in setting the searchQuery and UpdateQuery?